# How to re.split this line

Tags: python, regex

Want to split this line :

```
  1,        0.625,           0.,          2.5
```

to get output string like :

```
a = ["   " , "1" , "," , "     " , "0.625" , "," , "   " , "0." , "," , "    " , "2.5"]
```

so I could change value of for example `a[0] = 2` and at end get this :

```
  2,        0.625,           0.,          2.5
```

Is it possible? Please help

Comment: If you're trying to replace, you probably do not need to split first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` and put a group `(...)` around the things to split, e.g. `,|\s+`. This way, the separators are themselves part of the result. This produces some empty groups, though, between comma and space, which you have to filter out.

```
>>> s = "  1,        0.625,           0.,          2.5"
>>> [x for x in re.split(r"(,|\s+)", s) if x]
['  ', '1', ',', '        ', '0.625', ',', '           ', '0.', ',', '          ', '2.5']
```

Note, however, that if your goal is to replace values and keep some sort of tabular layout, this is more complicated than needed. Also, it does not work well if the new value has a different number of digits. Instead, you could just split by `,`, and when you replace a value, `rjust` the new value to the same width as the old value.

```
>>> vals = s.split(",")
>>> vals[2] = str(3.1415).rjust(len(vals[2]))
>>> ','.join(vals)
'  1,        0.625,       3.1415,          2.5'
>>> s
'  1,        0.625,           0.,          2.5'
```

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for answering this. Second, in fact, i have a different number of digits. I need to change some values from column 2. When I do that, commas disappear and I get columns without commas between them. For example, I should change number 3.1415 with 7.8888888. It is important that other tabs and spaces don't change. I open txt file and split it.

Comment: It is Abaqus input file and I am trying to change y coordinates of nodes . At end i would, with that changes, write a new input file and connect it with abaqus again so that is the reason why te other tabs should be the same as in original version.

Comment: @Badatprogramming I don't really understand your comment. When do commas disappear? Note that I `join` by `','`, whereas you probably joined with `''` before, as the `,` were still in the list.